# How to set Active class to Pagination element using NextJS with router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

I currently have a pagination element in which I return an array of values:

```js
const arrayPages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Then I have made it look like this:

```js
arrayPages.map((p, index) => (
  <li
    key={index}
    className={`page-item number-item ${
      arrayPages[index] === router.query.page ? `active` : ``
    }`}
  >
    <Link href={`${loadMoreParams.concat(`&page=${p}`)}`} passHref>
      <a className={`page-link`}>{p}</a>
    </Link>
  </li>
))
```

What I'm trying to do is to give the `active` class to the `<li>...</li>` element whenever the page from the  router.query matches with the element value?. This is the line that is giving me troubles:

```js
arrayPages[index] === router.query.page ? `active` : ``
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are the "troubles"? Are they any errors? Can you clarify what the issue is in more detail?

Comment: Can't you just do p.toString() === router.query.page ? 'active' : null?

Comment: @Matt , dude, I had it like that at first but without the `toString()` method. That fixed the problem! Big thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment just to get this question closed off the answer is.

```
...
className={`page-item number-item ${p.toString() === router.query.page ? `active` : null}`}
...
```

Glad i could help :)